# SSD replacement fails

Tags: ssd

I just got a new SSD (Samsung 850 EVO 256 GB) to replace the existing stock smaller Samsung SSD that was already in my Dell Latitude E6410 laptop. The new drive is only about 1/8" smaller than the old one length-wise but that's enough to not work together with the caddy. Without it, I can insert the new drive and make it work, but with the caddy, it physically stops before reaching the connectors in the back and doesn't quite make it. Any suggestions on how to make it work with the caddy?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't.  Its not compatible with the caddy

Comment: BluTack, perhaps? though, seriously, most caddies come with 72 different holes to screw them in with - pick the set that fits

Comment: Tetsujin, this one only has one hole, go figure.

Comment: The screw hole locations in reference to each other, the edges of the drive and the connectors should all be within spec.  Can you post some pictures of your original drive, the new drive and the caddy?  Preferably ones of each drive bolted into the caddy, from all important angles...